# Google subpages meta description

Tags: seo, meta

As you can see on the this image:
http://ahogenhaven.com/circoquestion.jpg

I'm trying to make Google show the subpage descriptions underneath the subpages.
For example for "Whats new" it's outputting something about an image file, but the meta description is "New arrivals at Circodellamoda.com, come and have a look at all the beautiful news from International luxury designers."

Does anyone know how I force it to show the correct meta description?

Answer (score 0):

These subpages displayed on Google are known as sitelinks. Sitelinks are automatically generated by Google. You have to enter your google webmaster tools account and re-index the subpage where you updated the meta-description (crawl/fetch as google/submitt to index). Hopefully soon the update will appear on search results.